# Retrieving data from shared prefrences

Tags: android, database, sharedpreferences

I am saving some data in the SharedPreferences, but when I press the back button and again go to profile, the data clears.
How can I keep data stored with the help of SharedPreferences?

```
    package www.edukeen.in.eduaspire;
    public class Profile extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText editTextName, editDOB, editphone, editcity, editclass, editboard, editschool, edithobbies, editachievements;
    Button buttonSave;

    public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs" ;
    public static final String Name = "nameKey";
    public static final String DOB = "DOBKey";
    public static final String Phone = "phoneKey";
    public static final String City = "cityKey";
    public static final String Class = "classKey";
    public static final String Board = "boardKey";
    public static final String School = "schoolKey";
    public static final String Hobbies = "hobbiesKey";
    public static final String Achievements = "achievementsKey";
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

        editTextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
        editDOB = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editDOB);
        editphone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editphone);
        editcity = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editcity);
        editclass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editclass);
        editboard = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editboard);
        editschool = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editschool);
        edithobbies = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edithobbies);
        editachievements = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editachievements);

        buttonSave=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonSave);
        sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);


        buttonSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String Name  = editTextName.getText().toString();
                String DOB  = editDOB.getText().toString();
                String Phone  = editphone.getText().toString();
                String City  = editcity.getText().toString();
                String Class  = editclass.getText().toString();
                String Board  = editboard.getText().toString();
                String School  = editschool.getText().toString();
                String Hobbies  = edithobbies.getText().toString();
                String Achievements  = editachievements.getText().toString();

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();

                editor.putString(Name, Name);
                editor.putString(DOB, DOB);
                editor.putString(Phone, Phone);
                editor.putString(City, City);
                editor.putString(Class, Class);
                editor.putString(Board, Board);
                editor.putString(School, School);
                editor.putString(Hobbies, Hobbies);
                editor.putString(Achievements, Achievements);

                editor.commit();
                Toast.makeText(Profile.this,"Data saved",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            String name = sharedpreferences.getString("name", "No name");
            String dob = sharedpreferences.getString("DOB", "");
            String phone = sharedpreferences.getString("phone", "");
            String city = sharedpreferences.getString("city", "");
            String clas = sharedpreferences.getString("class", "");
            String board = sharedpreferences.getString("board", "");
            String school = sharedpreferences.getString("school", "");
            String hobbies = sharedpreferences.getString("hobbies", "");
            String achievements = sharedpreferences.getString("achievements", "");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Also what should I do, if I want to get this data in my database?
I have already signed in a user, using firebase.

Comment: use editor.apply();

Comment: error is you are using same data for key and value when saving data and that too you are using reserved key words.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/29840449/2006803. And add "this." in the key side of the putString method

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Shared preferences example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024831/android-shared-preferences-example)

Answer (score 0):

Use this maybe it'll help you.

```
public class SharedPreferenceManager {

String APP_PREF = "APP_PREF";

public void setData(Context context, String key, int value) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences(APP_PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putInt(key, value);
    editor.apply();
}

public void setData(Context context, String key, long value) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences(APP_PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putLong(key, value);
    editor.apply();
}

public void setData(Context context, String key, String value) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences(APP_PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.apply();
}

public void setData(Context context, String key, float value) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences(APP_PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putFloat(key, value);
    editor.apply();
}

public void setData(Context context, String key, boolean value) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences(APP_PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putBoolean(key, value);
    editor.apply();
}

public String getString(Context context, String key) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(APP_PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return prefs.getString(key, null);
}

public int getInt(Context context, String key) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(APP_PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return prefs.getInt(key, 0);
}

public float getFloat(Context context, String key) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(APP_PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return prefs.getFloat(key, 0);
}

public long getLong(Context context, String key) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(APP_PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return prefs.getLong(key, 0);
}

public boolean getBool(Context context, String key) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(APP_PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return prefs.getBoolean(key, false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a common class for all shared prefrences work like this

```
public class SharedPrefManager {

    public static SharedPreferences getSharedPref(Context mContext) {
        SharedPreferences pref = mContext.getSharedPreferences(Constants.SETTINGS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        return pref;
    }

    public static void setPrefVal(Context mContext, String key, String value) {
        if(key!=null){
        Editor edit = getSharedPref(mContext).edit();
        edit.putString(key, value);
        edit.commit();
        }
    }

    public static void setIntPrefVal(Context mContext, String key, int value) {
        if(key!=null){
            Editor edit = getSharedPref(mContext).edit();
            edit.putInt(key, value);
            edit.commit();
        }
    }

    public static void setLongPrefVal(Context mContext, String key, Long value) {
        if(key!=null){
            Editor edit = getSharedPref(mContext).edit();
            edit.putLong(key, value);
            edit.commit();
        }
    }

    public static void setBooleanPrefVal(Context mContext, String key, boolean value) {
        if(key!=null){
            Editor edit = getSharedPref(mContext).edit();
            edit.putBoolean(key, value);
            edit.commit();
        }
    }


    public static String getPrefVal(Context mContext, String key) {
        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPref(mContext);
        String val = "";
        try {
            if (pref.contains(key))
                val = pref.getString(key, "");
            else
                val = "";
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return val;
    }

    public static int getIntPrefVal(Context mContext, String key) {
        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPref(mContext);
        int val = 0;
        try {
        if(pref.contains(key)) val = pref.getInt(key, 0);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return val;
    }

    public static Long getLongPrefVal(Context mContext, String key) {
        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPref(mContext);
        Long val = null;
        try{
        if(pref.contains(key)) val = pref.getLong(key, 0);
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
        return val;
    }

    public static boolean getBooleanPrefVal(Context mContext, String key) {
        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPref(mContext);
        boolean val = false;
        try{
        if(pref.contains(key)) val = pref.getBoolean(key, false);

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return val;
    }


    public static boolean containkey(Context mContext,String key)
    {
        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPref(mContext);
        return pref.contains(key);
    } 

    public static void saveTestScreens(Context mContext, String key,
            String value) {
        Editor edit = getSharedPref(mContext).edit();
        edit.putString(key, value);
        edit.commit();
    }

    public static String getTestScreens(Context mContext, String key) {
        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPref(mContext);
        String val = "";
        if (pref.contains(key))
            val = pref.getString(key, "");
        else
            val = "";
        return val;
    }
}
```

and then based on your requirements set and get data from shared prefrences

Answer (score 0):

try with this code

```
EditText editTextName, editDOB, editphone, editcity, editclass, editboard, editschool, edithobbies, editachievements;
Button buttonSave;

public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs";
public static final String Name = "nameKey";
public static final String DOB = "DOBKey";
public static final String PHONE = "phoneKey";
public static final String City = "cityKey";
public static final String CLASS = "classKey";
public static final String BOARD = "boardKey";
public static final String SCHOOL = "schoolKey";
public static final String HOBBIES = "hobbiesKey";
public static final String Achievements = "achievementsKey";
public String name, dOB, phone, city, classText, borad, school, hobbies, achievements;
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);


    editTextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
    editDOB = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editDOB);
    editphone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editphone);
    editcity = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editcity);
    editclass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editclass);
    editboard = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editboard);
    editschool = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editschool);
    edithobbies = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edithobbies);
    editachievements = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editachievements);

    buttonSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSave);
    sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    showText();
    buttonSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String name = editTextName.getText().toString();
            String DOBText = editDOB.getText().toString();
            String Phone = editphone.getText().toString();
            String city = editcity.getText().toString();
            String classText = editclass.getText().toString();
            String Board = editboard.getText().toString();
            String School = editschool.getText().toString();
            String Hobbies = edithobbies.getText().toString();
            String achievements = editachievements.getText().toString();

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();

            editor.putString(Name, name);
            editor.putString(DOB, DOBText);
            editor.putString(PHONE, Phone);
            editor.putString(City, city);
            editor.putString(CLASS, classText);
            editor.putString(BOARD, Board);
            editor.putString(SCHOOL, School);
            editor.putString(HOBBIES, Hobbies);
            editor.putString(Achievements, achievements);

            editor.commit();
            Toast.makeText(Test.this, "Data saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}

private void showText() {
    try {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
        editTextName.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(Name, ""));
        editDOB.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(DOB, ""));
        editphone.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(PHONE, ""));
        editcity.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(City, ""));
        editclass.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(CLASS, ""));
        editboard.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(BOARD, ""));
        editschool.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(SCHOOL, ""));
        edithobbies.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(HOBBIES, ""));
        editachievements.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(Achievements, ""));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```